# Perl, Input dates on the command line and calculates the number of days between the two dates

Tags: perl, date, input, difference

I know how to subtract 2 static dates that I can assign within the code, but is there a way I can input 2 dates on the command line and get the number of days between the 2?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. However, as it is currently written, this question is off-topic because: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be about getting two values into your program, rather than about calculating the number of days between two dates. So here are a couple of approaches you can take.

Command line arguments passed to your program end up in `@ARGV`. So

```
my ($date1, $date2) = @ARGV;
```

And then call the program as:

```
$ ./date_diff 2015-12-25 2015-11-24
```

Or you could ask the user for the dates:

```
print "Give me a date :";
chomp(my $date1) = <STDIN>;
print "Give me another date :";
chomp(my $date2) = <STDIN>;
```